# Evento com e, sem addEventlistener não saõ iguais?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Porque isto não funciona:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'wait a minute'
})
```

E isto funciona:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'wait a minute'
}
```

Não são a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os dois não funcionam da mesma forma. O `addEventListener` com o evento `beforeunload` requer `event.returnValue`:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event){

   var mensagem = "wait a minute";
   event.returnValue = mensagem;
   return mensagem;

});
```

Mais informações **[neste documento do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)**<sup>em inglês</sup>.

Comment: Show!! É isso mesmo, valeu!!