# Métodos onunload e o onbeforeunload não funcionam

Tags: javascript

Me baseando nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842590/run-function-when-page-is-loaded) eu gostaria de que quando o usuario fechasse a aba(ou atualizasse) recebesse um alert dizendo `Tchau`, porem apenas quando eu entro na pagina ele me diz `Olá`, quando atualizo ou fecho a aba, ele não me diz `Tchau`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){alert('Olá')};
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){alert('Tchau')};
    window.onunload = function(){alert('Tchau')};
</script>
```

Lembrando que também já tentei dessa forma

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){alert('Olá')}
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){return 'Tchau';}
    window.onunload = function(){return 'Tchau';}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondi a uma questão parecida **[aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263488/8063)**.

Mas para o método `window.onbeforeunload` funcionar, é preciso colocar um `return`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Tchau';
}
```

No entanto, alguns navegadores não exibem a mensagem do `return`, mas apenas uma caixa de confirmação própria (se não me engano, o Chrome, Firefox e Opera).

### Edit

O método `onunload` é executado após a janela ser fechada. Portanto não exibirá nada. Já o `onbeforeunload` faz algo antes de fechar.

[Veja documentação no MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)

### Edit 2

O método `window.onbeforeunload` só irá funcionar também se houver alguma interação na página. Caso o usuário abra a página e a feche sem ter feito nenhuma interação, não haverá confirmação.

### Edit 3

Em vez de fazer um `window.onload`, você pode criar um modal de *boas-vindas* e forçar o usuário a clicar, nisso gerando uma interação. Veja o código ([teste online neste link](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/unload.php)):

```css
#tela {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#aviso{
   width: 300px;
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   z-index: 999;
   top: 50%;
   align-self: center;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="tela">
   <div id="aviso">
      Olá!
      <br /><br />
      <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="document.querySelector('#tela').style.display = 'none';" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta, eu já tentei dessa forma e também não consegui.

Comment: E há alguma forma de testar se está funcionando no google chrome ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia funciona perfeitamente. Veja uma página de teste [neste link](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/unload.php). Tente sair clicando no link, recarregar a página ou fechar a aba.

Comment: Você tinha comentado um outro método, porem apagou o comentário, poderia coloca-lo novamente ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia onde?

Comment: Aqui mesmo, você disse para mim testar outro método(diferente do onunload e onbeforeunload) no Chrome, porem você apagou o comentário, e eu estava curioso quando ao método.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Não seria o link que está na resposta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263488/8063

Comment: Só pra constar: a capacidade de definir uma `{String}` ao evento **"onbeforeunload"** foi removida no [Chrome 51](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480), Safari 9.1 e Firefox 4

Comment: @LauroMoraes Pois eh, o Chrome, o FF e o Opera (se não me engano) ignoram strings. Eles mostram um box próprio de confirmação.

Comment: @dvd Foi um método `window.algumacoisa` mesmo. Mas não tem problema. Há alguma forma de capturar o evento unload mesmo com o usuário não interagindo com a pagina ??(se preferir eu abro outra pergunta).

Comment: @LucasCarezia Espera um pouco que vou ver... já já te falo

Comment: Apartir do [Chrome 60](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5082396709879808) e [Firefox 44](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=636905) respectivamente os eventos **"beforeunload"** e **"onbeforeunload"** requerem que o usuário tenha ao menos uma interação com a página

Comment: @LauroMoraes E não tem como "burlar" isso ??

Comment: Não. Isso é padrão do navegador implícito em suas "**politicas"**. O correto seria seguir a resposta dada pelo @dvd e alinhar a uma estratégia que faça o usuário interagir ao menos uma vez com a página.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Creio que não tem como. O navegador bloqueia qualquer tentativa de burlar isso, mesmo simulando interação.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou fazer isso. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @LucasCarezia De nada. Depois com mais tempo vou explorar mais isso, vai que acho uma brexa. Aí te aviso.

Comment: @dvd  Perfeito, fico no aguardo.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Coloquei uma atualização na resposta. É uma forma de forçar o usuário a clicar na página.

Answer (score 2):

Já falei disto algumas vezes:

- [Função OnUnload JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127013/3635)
- [Como pegar evento que fecha o browser?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256171/3635)
- [Jquery beforeunload é chamado quando clico em link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80702/3635)

Pra resumir as respostas, onunload e onbeforeunload **não servem** para detectar quando a pessoa deixa o site, o que ele faz é detectar o **descarregamento**, ou seja se navegar em um link do mesmo site vai disparar o evento, se apertar F5, vai disparar o evento, se usar o <kbd>Back</kbd> ou <kbd>Forward</kbd> vai disparar o evento.

Ainda sim se quiser usar, é necessário primeiro entender algumas coisas, quando o unload ou beforeunload ocorrem a página já esta em pré-processo de destruir/descarregar e portanto não vão ser geradas novas janelas/GUIs.

Ou seja, `alert()`, `confirm()`, `prompt()` e `window.open()` não serão executados, mesmo que você deseje, isto é explicado na especificação da W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#user-prompts

> **nota:** alert/confirm e outros também são ignorados no evento `pagehide`

Então o único evento que você deve usar é o `beforeunload` com o `return '<string>';`, tem mais um problema o seu HTML esta mal marcado, não é que isto afete a execução, mas ainda sim deveria ser isto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //script vai aqui
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

No entanto note que mesmo usando:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Tchau';
};
```

**Não vai emitir o texto desejado**, ele vai **apenas** gerar uma mensagem padrão perguntando se quer ou não descarregar a página:

[image: janela de confirmação de saida com o evento beforeunload]

Ou seja isso não é uma mensagem apenas de "adeus", e nem é exibido o `Tchau`, é um recurso para ser usado em certas ocasiões, para dizer tchau com certeza não é uma boa maneira de implementar isto.

### Proporcionando uma boa experiência para o usuário

Dizer oi, dizer tchau, será que isto é realmente necessário? Será que o usuário não sabe que já esta de saida ou quando entrou na página?

Eu pessoalmente creio que estes tipos de mensagem soam mais como ruido do que como algo útil ao usuário, tanto que por muitos destes problemas é que certas implementações foram removidas dos navegadores, muitas coisas mais causam aquela sensação *"a não, de novo essa mensagem"*, do que realmente parecer educado, o usuário vai se sentir bem vindo no site quando ele conseguir o que deseja do site, e não com uma mensagem de boas vindas perturbadora que trava tudo até que seja apertado no botão `ok`.

Sobre o uso de `beforeunload` e `unload` já expliquei, eles não são para checar quando a pessoa sai do site, e não existe maneira garantida de fazer isto, dá pra implementar qualquer coisa, detectar links internos e externos, mas este tipo de coisa é trabalho desnecessário, recomendo pessoalmente que se foque em criar uma interface agradável de navegar para que o usuário se sinta bem ao navegar, então ai sim ele vai se sentir bem vindo e quando sair do site com certeza ele uma hora irá querer voltar.

### Qual seria a utilidade do beforeunload?

Ele seria mais interessante se usado para impedir que perca edições feitas, ou se for um jogo impedir que saia sem salvar o jogo, pois é exatamente isto que a mensagem padrão diz:

> Deseja sair deste site?
>
> É possível que alterações feitas não tenham sido salvas

Esse é o foco dele atualmente, impedir de que o usuário feche algo acidentalmente e perca algo.

Comment: Sua resposta foi ótima, meu intuito com o Olá e Tchau era apenas de testes, para ver como funcionava os métodos, mas sua resposta foi excepcional, obrigado.

Comment: @LucasCarezia aproveite e leia os links, quando puder claro, sobre tipo checar se o usuário ainda esta online ou não, usando um temporizador